# Admin page not being created with hook_menu

Tags: forms, routes

I created an admin page with [hook_menu](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) but the page is not showing.  This is on a fresh Drupal 7.23 install.

```
function my_module_permission() {
  return array(
    'administer my_module settings' => array(
      'title' => t('Administer My Module Settings'),
      'description' => t('Change settings for My Module.'),
    ),
    'initiate my_module migration' => array(
      'title' => t('Run the My Module function'),
      'description' => t('Initiate the My Module function.'),
    ),
  );
}

function my_module_admin() {
  $form = array();

  $form['my_module_xml_file'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Local file location'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('my_module_xml_file'),
    '#description' => t('The path to the XML file to import.'),
  );

  return system_settings_form($form);
}

function my_module_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['admin/config/development/my-module'] = array(
    'title' => 'My module migrate settings',
    'description' => 'Change settings for My Module',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('my_module_admin'),
    'access arguments' => array('administer my_module settings'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );

  return $items;

}
```

Comment: Hate to ask the obvious, but... 1) is the module enabled? 2) did you clear the menu registry (ie. clear cache). 3) does the user you're using have access to that page? 4) can you access the URI directly, without going through the menu?

Comment: @YuriyBabenko 1. Yes, 2. Yes, 3. This user should have access, he is the only user, admin. 4. Going to the url just brings me to admin/config/development instead of admin/config/development/my-module

Comment: try removing the hyphen in the path

Comment: Odd thing:  `access callback` is set to TRUE yet you are giving it `access arguments`.  Try removing this to have it default to `user_access()`.  Also/then make sure the access argument you have is PRECISELY correct against permissions.

Comment: @ScottJoudry This did not work.

Comment: @Jimajamma I tried getting rid of access argument, then access callback, then both, but this did not work.  I also made sure the permissions are inline exactly in every case.

Comment: if you remove `access arguments` but leave in `access callback` set to TRUE, anyone *should* be able to access this.  Alas, given that when you try to go to the path, it goes to the parent strongly suggests that it isn't being even called at all.

Comment: Another oddity:  `$form['my_module_xml_file']` doesn't match `variable_get('my_module_xmlfile'),` so make sure they are exactly the same, eg, the key of the `$form` array has to/should match the variable.

Comment: @Jimajamma Sorry, that was something I had miss-spelled when typing question.  I've fixed it in the original question.

Comment: usually these sort of things are what I call "off by one errors" so if you could copy and paste your exact `hook_menu()` function here we might be able to see what's not working.

Comment: Try going to the page as the super user (user ID 1). If you can get to the page then the page is working and it is definitely a permissions issue. It would also be worth posting your code for your hook_permission() function. - Definitely get rid of 'access callback' = TRUE - You shouldn't have that there unless you want everyone to see the page.

Comment: I have checked your code with `'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),` and its working fine. You need to implement `hook_permission` in your code.

Comment: @JayendraKainthola  Something else on my site must be conflicting as this permission did not work either.  I also have the hook_permission set up already.

Comment: @CR47 If the problem is with `hook_permission()` it'd be good if you could dump that function into the question too

Comment: @Clive Added it.

Comment: @CR47, I have checked your updated code and its generating admin link. Please check this in other drupal installation.